# SQL Update, if not exist then insert

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

Table Layout:

```
CREATE TABLE gmod_playerdata (
  dataset_id  int(255) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data_id int(255) NULL,
  option_name  varchar(100) NULL,
  option_value  varchar(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (dataset_id)
)
```

I can't know whether the row already exists or not. `data_id` will always be filled, but can/will appear multiple times.

I only need to update option_name and option_value, while I don't know if a option_value and option_name already exist when I run the query.

I've read much about `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` however I kinda don't get how it is meant to be used in my scenario.

Comment: are option_value and option_name together unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming combinations of `option_value` and `option_name` are unique...

For `on duplicate key update` to work, there must be a unique index (or a primary key), so:

```
create unique index myidx on gmod_playerdata(option_value, option_name);
```

Once the index is created, this query will work:

```
insert into gmod_playerdata values (...)
on duplicate key update data_id = values(data_id)
```

I have assumed since `data_id` is the only other real column, that you want to update that instead of inserting a row. If that isn't what you want, adjust the query following the syntax.

Comment: Thanks! You've pointed me in the right direction. I'm using "UNIQUE KEY `attribute` (`data_id`,`option_name`) USING BTREE" now and this way I can also also use ON DUPLICATE Key.